# Custom create method to prevent duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to add some logic to my serializer.py.

Currently it creates duplicate tags (giving a new ID to the item, but often it will match a tag name already).

## In plain english

```
if exists:
   # Find the PK that matches the "name" field
   # "link" the key with Movie Class item
else:
   # Create the "name" inside of Tag class
   # "link" the key with Movie Class item
```

## The data being posted looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "Test",
  "tag": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "taglevel": 1
    }
  ],
  "info": [

  ]
}
```

## Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Whats happening?", max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

### Serializers

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'tag', 'info')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            movie.tag.create(**tag_data)
        return movie
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will probably solve your issue:

```
tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)[0]
movie.tag.add(tag)
```

`get_or_create` function returns tuple `(instance, created)`, so you have to get `instance` with `[0]`.

So the full code is:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
    movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tag_data in tags_data:
        tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)[0]
        movie.tag.add(tag)
    return movie
```

To make function case insensitive, you have to do "get or create" manually (the main part is to use `__iexact` in `filter`):

```
tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])
if tag_qs.exists():
    tag = tag_qs.first()
else:
    tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
movie.tag.add(tag)
```

Comment: Please show me the code in full (including the def create)

Comment: I've added the whole function.

Comment: That did not work. This tells me- int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tag'. Here is the full traceback http://dpaste.com/3CER9FG

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I've updated the snippet and added the explanation. It should work now.

Comment: Great! Lastly, how do I make it ignore the case (case insensitive) so it would see both "HELLO" and "hello" as the same?

Comment: Just add `tag_data['name'] = tag_data['name'].lower()` before `tag = Tag...`, so all entries in the database will be lowercase.

Comment: I will have some cases where an item uses camel-casing (eg ReactNative). It would not be good to store everything as lowercase... How can I handle this?